# How to change Finder icon on macOS Catalina?

Tags: finder, icon, catalina

On previous versions of macOS, it was possible to change the Finder icon in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/`.

However, this doesn't seem possible in Catalina anymore? Even with SIP disabled?

Comment: Aha I think this might be the answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367892/cannot-change-login-wallpaper-in-10-15-catalina

Answer (score 1):

Based on this answer: [Cannot change login wallpaper in 10.15 Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367892/cannot-change-login-wallpaper-in-10-15-catalina)

1. Reboot Mac, holding <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to boot into Recovery mode
2. Open terminal
3. Disable SIP with `csrutil disable`
4. Reboot Mac
5. Open a terminal
6. `sudo mount -uw /`
7. `sudo cp ~/your-new-icon.png /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/finder.png`
8. Repeat for `finder@2x.png`
9. Reboot into recovery
10. Re-enable SIP with `csrutil enable`

Comment: You should not need to disable SIP and do the reboot dance! Simply make the change while booted to the Recovery HD and note that the `path` will be e.g.:  `"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/.."`

Comment: Interesting. Will definitely have to give that a go next time!

Comment: Just wanted to note that this method still works as of 10.15.7