# Cannot change login wallpaper in 11.x Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur

Similar to [the question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367892/cannot-change-login-wallpaper-in-10-15-catalina), is there a way to change the login background wallpaper in Big Sur? During the beta, I was able to do it via a combination of the procedures in Catalina and the **bless** command described at https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/

This doesn't seem to work with 11.0.1 (20B29). It keeps reverting to the com.apple.os.update-779B* snapshot. Note that I am using FileVault.

Thanks

Comment: Can this maybe help you? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418363/how-do-i-change-the-login-screen-background-in-macos-big-sur/418376#418376

Comment: Did you find any solution for changing login wallpaper in big sur when filevault is on?

Comment: No, I’d provide feedback to Apple: https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

FileVault has to be OFF, to use a non-system sealed shapshot to boot Big Sur

Comment: Don't know if this is true, but I've read if you break the seal you'll no longer be able to use FileVault.