# How do I change the login screen background in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: big-sur, filevault

I'm asking for help with FileVault enabled.

A similar question was [answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337881/413807)  for Mojave, but their Swift program doesn't work in Big Sur because `/Library/Desktop Pictures/Mojave.heic` no longer exists.

Comment: Did you look for any other file with an heic extension?

Comment: There exists `Big Sur Graphic.heic`, which looks like the one used in the FileVault login screen, how could I modify the answer used in Mojave to see if it works for me?

Comment: No answers but see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406879/cannot-change-login-wallpaper-in-11-x-big-sur

Answer (score 2):

The background of the login screen is in this location

```
/Library/Caches/Desktop\ Pictures/<a specific string>/lockscreen.png
```

If only **one user** is registered on your system, you will see a folder with a picture that is displayed on your lock screen and one from the **system** for which you first need higher rights to view it.

The lock screen folder of the **system** is there so that if, for example, several people are registered and just want to log in, this image then appears for everyone. The system doesn't know exactly who wants to log in, so there is a lock screen for everyone first. But if the **user** has clicked on his profile and wants to enter his password, he will see his lock screen again.

By the specific string, I literally mean the UUID, which you can look up:

`Go to System Preferences` > `Users & Groups` > `Your Account` > `Right Click (Advanced Options)` > `Now you will see your UUID`

Comment: **Note:** You need to first unlock the _pane_ in order to _right-click_ on the **user account** to get the **Advanced Options…** pop-up menu.

Comment: Also note that if FileVault is enabled, you will no longer be able to change the loginwindow background.

Comment: In the Terminal, `dscl . list /users GeneratedUID | grep $USER` shows the UUID of the current user.

Comment: @lhf Slightly more concise (outputs only the UUID): `dscl . -read $HOME GeneratedUID | cut -d' ' -f2`