# How to disable lock screen animation on Catalina

Tags: catalina

I saw that the lock screen in Catalina are animating in background, how to disable those annoying animation and just replace it with plain black image?

Comment: This any use? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367892/cannot-change-login-wallpaper-in-10-15-catalina?rq=1

Comment: Animating?  Never seen that before.

Comment: In the list choice of screen savers, there is one with "Message". By defaut the message is your computer name, but you can modify it with a "space".

You have only a black screen with an apple.

Comment: The only way that helped me on Sonoma 14.0 was to set a static Wallpaper in the System Settings. Changing any of the Screen Saver or Lock Screen settings didn't help.